# Disable or prevent multitouch in Activity

Tags: android, multi-touch

I have several Views on an Activity which a user wants to touch quickly in succession and I capture these touches using a `TouchListener` and handling `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. However, if the user is using two hands, it's very likely that the next View will be 'Touch'ed before the user pulls the previous finger up. In this scenario, a `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` is fired for the first view rather than the desired `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` for the second view.

Is there any way to work around or prevent this behavior? I've tried dispatching a new event with `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and also removing the event listener but neither seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to work around this scenario is to use a `ViewGroup` and implement the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method to manually route the touch events as you see fit.

This was originally answered here:
[Android multitouch! hack anyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5938970/102443)

Code implementing this solution (found in the comments section of the answer to the above question) is found here:
http://pastebin.com/hiE1aTCw

Answer (score 90):

The easiest way I found to force single touch across an entire app is to set it using a theme:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
  <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
```

Comment: Just for information, "android:splitMotionEvents" requires API level 11 and above

Comment: Working for me in Android 5.0.1.

Comment: Works fine even on Android 8.

Answer (score 29):

if someone still searching for best solution,
put in the xml the following code :

```
android:splitMotionEvents = false
```

Comment: It should be put inside a layout.

Comment: Yes it works! Insert it in the layout where u need disable the multitouch.

Comment: use it in the parent layout and it will get the job done

Comment: use this in a layout which have clickable items, don't place it in top most layout/root view.

Answer (score 7):

I did it like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        System.out.println("Multitouch detected!");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I think you can override onTouchEvent for any view.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this using a custom method - which I did not want to do If anyone finds a better way I'd like to hear about it Thanks:

```
public static void setViewGroupEnebled(ViewGroup view, boolean enabled)
{
    int childern = view.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i< childern ; i++)
    {
        View child = view.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup)
        {
            setViewGroupEnebled((ViewGroup) child,enabled);
        }
        child.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    view.setEnabled(enabled);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override dispatchTouchEvent and intercept all touches there, for all multi touches the pointercount is more than one.

```
 if(ev.getPointerCount() > 1)
  {
     Log.d("Multitouch detected!");
     ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
  }
```

This cancels the touches and clears the pressed state of the buttons without taking any further action.

Comment: First time it work, second time when I make multitouch then I make one touch it's not detected.

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked like this.
I just put this line in all active styles in my app

```
<item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
```

my style for example

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
      <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

            if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

                horizentalLinearGridItem.setMotionEventSplittingEnabled(false);

            }
```

Here horizentalLinearGridItem is parentLayout view where we insert child views.
In my code its LinearLayout. In this LinearLayout I added child views. But when I clicked two child views simultaneously, both were getting the events. To block that I used the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work for me by just adding some code in `OnTouchEvent` method,

```
boolean action_down_required = false;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();

    if(event.getPointerCount() > 1){
        action_down_required = true;
        return true;
    }

    if(action_down_required){
        action = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
    }

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            // your code goes here...

            action_down_required = false;
            break;

        // Other events...
```