# Disabling multi-touch on my app

Tags: android, multi-touch

For some reasons I have to disable the multi-touch feature on my app. The user can press only one button at a time, or the app would crash. Is there any way to implement this requirement?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See the answers for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570982/disable-or-prevent-multitouch-in-activity

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To prevent this you should turn off [splitMotionEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#splitMotionEvents) or [windowEnableSplitTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowEnableSplitTouch) attribute inside ViewGroup were buttons are located.

```
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
```

Comment: So what happens if an app has a deep view hierarchy and there are buttons at the leaf nodes of the hierarchy? We need to mark every ViewGroup up to the root with this attribute?

Comment: Yes you are right, second approach is to create custom view group and override `onTouchEvent` there. Example is here: http://goo.gl/pRXtCk

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your manifest

```
< uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I don't think that a <uses-feature> tag will disable a feature.. See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html