# Dynamically creating multiple imageButtons Makes drag and drop difficult

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, imagebutton, android-framelayout

I have a dialog menu setup for the user to pick a building which they wish to build. When they press the buy button, the building is automatically inserted into the activity. The issue is that when more than one is bought, then moving the most recently bought building will also move the second most recently bought building. I am not positive how to fix this issue. I would see if setting the new buildings in a frame layout rather than a linear layout would help, but my drag and drop does not work if I do it that way.

Here is the code for the imagebutton being set up after the buy button is pressed:

```
            layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.newColonyHutLayout);
            buyColonyHut = (Button) buildingSelect.findViewById(R.id.buyColonyHut);
            buyColonyHut.setText("Buy");
            buyColonyHut.setBackgroundColor(-65536);
            buyColonyHut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //get current amount of rock and check if it is enough to buy
                    data = new Database(runGraphics.this);
                    data.open();
                    rockAmount = data.getRockAmount();
                    data.close();
                    if (rockAmount >= 100)
                    {
                        //take away spent money and update database
                        data.open();
                        rockAmount -= 100;
                        data.rockAmountEntry(rockAmount);
                        data.close();

                        //update the scores
                        updateScores();

                        //close the dialog
                        buildingSelect.dismiss();
                        buildMoreButton.setBackgroundColor(-65536);

                        //they have enough rock, build the building
                        newColonyHut = new ImageButton(runGraphics.this);
                        newColonyHut.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mainhut);
                        newColonyHut.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        layout.addView(newColonyHut);
                        newColonyHut.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                        {   
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                            {
                                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                                {
                                    newColonyHutSelected = true;
                                }//end if

                                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                                {
                                    if (newColonyHutSelected == true)
                                    {
                                        newColonyHutSelected = false;
                                    }//end if
                                }//end if
                                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                                {
                                    if (newColonyHutSelected == true)
                                    {
                                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
                                        params.setMargins((int)(event.getRawX() - event.getRawY() / 5), (int) (event.getRawY() - v.getHeight()), (int) (event.getRawX() - v.getWidth() / 5), (int) (event.getRawY() - v.getHeight()));
                                        v.setLayoutParams(params);
                                    }//end if
                                }//end else

                                return false;
                            }//end onTouch function

                        });//end setOnTouchListener
                    }//end onClick function
                });//end onClickListener
```

here is the xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newColonyHutLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/newColonyHut"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mainhut" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to implement drag drop, you can use drag drop provided by android. It can work on API level 11 and above. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570982/disable-or-prevent-multitouch-in-activity Check this link, maybe it will help in avoiding multi-touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return `true` at the end of the `onTouch()` Method to notify that the TouchEvent was consumed by the listener. Otherwise subsequent listeners of the View below that View that was touched will be called -  e.g. the one of your second building.

Another idea would be to use the `View.onDragListener`, instead of implementing the drag&drop completely on your own. Here's a good example how to use it: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html#draganddrop_overview

Comment: If he return true, it will consume event at ACTION_DOWN and will not allow ACTION_MOVE.

Comment: Okay, how about the View.OnDragListener instead of implementing the Drag & Drop completely on your own?

Comment: That is a good option, easy to implement, but need API 11 and above. However, this is an alternate.

Comment: So you're saying using View.OnDragListener will work in a framelayout? Or are you saying that it will stop the movement of previously created imagebuttons by itself in a linearlayout?

Comment: @saboehnke Are you inflating each view in frame layout? And adding touch listener on each of them?

Comment: Yes I am adding touch listener on each.

Comment: @saboehnke I guess its the problem. All of them have touch listeners, so maybe all of them are intercepting it.

Comment: I'd say that using the View.OnDragListener like in the example I linked, will stop the Drag&Drop to affect multiple of the Views

Comment: @saboehnke Can you tell me the purpose of adding them in a frame and moving them?

Comment: The user is buying buildings and is able to move them where they would like them to be on the screen.

Comment: Is that necessary? Maybe I am misunderstanding what they are using the multi-touch for in that article, but he mentions using more than one hand and that is not what I am worried about.

Comment: @saboehnke oh yea, sorry.

Comment: No problem. I will give the ondraglistener a shot and I will comment on results

Comment: The OnDragListener API fixed my issue.