# Is possible to enable only 1st finger touch event in my android application using any filter like a transparent GestureOverlayView?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new in Android application development and I don't know if there is any good tactic for this. Specifically, I want all my fragments and activities to recognise only the first touch on the screen and ignore any other. If anyone knows a better way just let me know..

Until now i have tried to add:

`<item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>` in my xml style 
and i also add `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />` in my manifest file

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable or prevent multitouch in Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570982/disable-or-prevent-multitouch-in-activity)

Comment: As i said before i have activity and fragments inside. Its not only problem in my activity. I believe from that maybe i need to use a GestureOverlayView and allow the first touch event..So i restate my topic to be more accurate..

Comment: I do believe you will have to handle this in `onTouch` Listeners. Most default ones such as `onClickListener` or `onLongClickListener` will already handle multi touches, so that the "first targeted View" is the source of the event, and everything is are qualifiers.