# Buttons are behaving strangely when using the "multitouch hack"

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am writing a Quiz. I have four buttons: answer options, and i am using [Android multitouch! hack anyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938970/android-multitouch-hack-anyone) code snippet to disable multitouch.

But the buttons seem to work only if you tap on them **very quickly.**

If you slowly press the button and then release it, button only blinks, and nothing happens. Could someone help me figure out how to fix this?

Comment: You can try to make a boolean flag that can be set to true if a button is pressed and whenever the button is pressed check if the flag is true and if it is, you can just do nothing.. I think it will simplify your work.. let us know if this is not a good idea for you

Comment: @Cata
i have tried smthing like `public void acceptAnswer(View v) {
  if (isTriggered){
   return;
  }
  isTriggered = true;
  switch (v.getId()) ...` but that does not work (I also can't figure out why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [@JQCorreia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938970/android-multitouch-hack-anyone?lq=1) hack and overrided his "onTouchEvent" like this:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            for(View v: views){
                Rect r = new Rect();
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
                if (event.getX() > r.left && event.getX() < r.right
                        && event.getY() > r.top
                        && event.getY() < r.bottom) {
                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            for(View v: views){
                Rect r = new Rect();
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
                if (event.getX() > r.left && event.getX() < r.right
                        && event.getY() > r.top
                        && event.getY() < r.bottom) {
                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            for(View v: views){
                Rect r = new Rect();
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
                if (event.getX() > r.left && event.getX() < r.right
                        && event.getY() > r.top
                        && event.getY() < r.bottom) {
                }
                else{
                    v.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that might work, please note that I didn't had the time to try it..

```
private static final String sClickKey = "clickkey";
private boolean mClicked;

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    synchronized (sClickKey){

        if (!mClicked){
            mClicked = true;
            /* do the rest here... */
        }

    }

}
```

Using `synchronize` will ensure that only the first tapped button will enter in the `if(!mClicked)`, after that the `mClicked` value is changed to `true` so the next event will not pass in the if statement..

I hope this helps! ;)